# Can I use google place autocomplete to search for locations on iOS, then place results on Apple Maps?

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit

I know that I have to add a "Powered By Google" logo to the area where I'm performing the operations, but will google be ok with me using the data that I receive to display them on an MKMapView? If they are ok with it, will I have to place the "Powered By Google" logo on the MKMapView too? or should it only be on the UITableView holding the results?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not.

According to [Google Places API Web Service Policies](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies#logo_requirements),

> If your application displays Google Places API Web Service data on a map, that map must be provided by Google.